# Missing back button when using popToViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

In my 4th view controller I did the following:

```
NSArray * viewCtrllr = [self.navigationController viewController];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[viewCtrllr objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

This pops it to the 2nd view controller in stack however I am not seeing the back button. If I just do a regular popViewController then I can see all the view controller with the back button on it. How is this even possible? I am not hiding the back button, double checked on that

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[viewCtrllr objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

Pops to root view controller (first). So no any more view controllers are under it and there is no back button.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it is actually 1 not 0